# ColdFusion Builder RDS Query Viewer Inserts Allowed?

Tags: coldfusion, derby, coldfusion-9, coldfusionbuilder

Just started using ColdFusion Builder 2 with ColdFusion 9 and saw the RDS viewer ability in it. I thumbed through Forta's WACK book and tried a simple example from it, a basic INSERT using a Derby Embedded database:

```
INSERT INTO Directors(FirstName,LastName)
VALUES('Ben','Forta')
```

If you execute that query using the RDS Query Viewer you get an error:

```
Statement.executeQuery() cannot be used with a query that returns a row count.
```

Are INSERTs, DELETEs, and UPDATEs not allowed using this tool? I'm probably just spoiled using SQL Server's Management Studio which will let you do anything if you have the rights.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, AFAIK  INSERTs, DELETEs, and UPDATEs not allowed

Comment: Not allowed at all, with *any* databases ...?

Comment: Aha...got it. I guess a more informative error message would've helped. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that said one way or the other, but I could've missed it.  Thanks!